# Iterate through a Pandas DataFrame with multiple handles, and iteratively append edited rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, handle

I have 3 dataframes:

- `df1` with match history (organized by date)
- `df2` with player stats (organized by player name)
- `df3` difference between player stats (`df2`) per match (`df1`) [in progress]

I want to do something like:

```py
    for idx, W_nm, L_nm in df1[['index','winner_name','loser_name']].values:
      df3.loc[idx] = df2.loc[W_nm] - df2.loc[L_nm]
      #... edit this row further
```

Which fails because:

- `'idx'` doesn't reference `df1`'s indices
- `df3` has no defined columns

Is there a way to reference the indices on the first line?

I've read `iterrows()` is 7x slower than `.loc[]` and I have quite a bit of data to process

Is there anything cleaner than this:

```py
    for idx in df1.index:
      W_nm = df1.loc[idx,'winner_name']
      L_nm = df1.loc[idx,'loser_name']
      df3.loc[idx] = df2.loc[W_nm] - df2.loc[L_nm]
      #... edit this row further
```

Which doesn't fix the "no defined columns", but gives me my handles.

So I'm expecting something like:

```py
 df1
[            'Loser'  'Winner'   'Score'
  0          Harry    Hermione   3-7   ...
  1          Harry    Ron        0-2   ...
  2          Ron      Voldemort  7-89   ... ]

 df2
[            'Spells' 'Allies'
  Harry      23       84      ...
  Hermione   94       68      ...
  Ron        14       63      ...
  Voldemort  97       92      ... ]

then

df3
[            'Spells' 'Allies'
  0          -71      16      ...
  1          9        21      ...
  2          -83      -29     ... ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is `join`:

```
loser = df1.join(df2, on='Loser').loc[:,['Spells', 'Allies']]
winner = df1.join(df2, on='Winner').loc[:,['Spells', 'Allies']]
df3 = winner - loser
```

With your example data is gives:

```
   Spells  Allies
0      71     -16
1      -9     -21
2      83      29
```

Comment: Is there a shorthand for all-columns-of-df2 e.g. ['Spells', 'Allies', ... all]?

Comment: Found it: df.columns